# Why This Function is not working to zoho mail?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

//send email function

```
public function sendemail(){

    $from1 = $this->input->post('from');//input name
    $to1 = $this->input->post('to');//input name
    $subject1 = $this->input->post('subject');//input name
    $message1 = $this->input->post('message');//input name
    $config = Array(
          'protocol' => 'smtp',
          'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
          'smtp_port' => 465,
          'smtp_user' => 'malinga@bckonnect.com',
          'smtp_pass' => 'mal@pass',
          'mailtype' => 'html'
    );
    $this->load->library('email', $config);//load library Codeigniter
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    // Set to, from, message, etc.
    $this->email->to($to1);
    $this->email->from($from1,$from1);
    //$this->email->bcc("example2@domain.com"); 
    $this->email->subject($subject1);
    $this->email->message($message1);    
    $result = $this->email->send();

    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success">Message Sent Successfully!</div>');
    redirect('welcome/index');

}
```

this is my email function code.it is working for gmail.but it is not working for Zoho mail.Why?

Comment: They may be blocking you or filtering your email as spam

Answer (score 0):

You should add Zoho mail SMPT configuration:

```
Outgoing Server Name: smtp.zoho.com
Port: 465 with SSL or
Port: 587 with TLS
Require Authentication: Yes
```

So it will be like

```
 $config = Array(
          'protocol' => 'smtp',
          'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.zoho.com',
          'smtp_port' => 465,
          'smtp_user' => 'malinga@bckonnect.com',
          'smtp_pass' => 'mal@pass',
          'mailtype' => 'html'
    );
```

Reference : https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/imap-access.html

Comment: i already use this.but it was not working

Comment: Have you tried all the steps in the link, I posted in answer?

Comment: okay please give me a new answer